# Starting rider mower

Tags: lawn-mower

Hi is it safe  to start my rider mower inside a shed with the doors wide open in order to drive it out?  Rather than push it out to the lawn  manually and then start.

Comment: What do you call safe? You will not die instantly of it, but if you do this every day, it could cause premature death due to bad lung health.

Answer (score 1):

What could go wrong?

- Starting it inside the shed doesn't have enough ventilation, so you breathe a toxic amount of carbon monoxide. This seems like a relatively small problem as long as you get moving quickly. You'll probably have to use your own judgment here based on how your lungs feel after driving it out once or twice.
- With the motor running, perhaps the blade also moves and it slices into the ramp as you exit the shed. I guess you'd only do that once before figuring out how to disengage or adjust the ramp or drive at an angle so this isn't a problem.
- You hit reverse instead of drive (or vice versa) and end up smashing through the wall of the shed.

And, as always, you should wear personal protection equipment while riding the mower such as hearing protection, eye protection, and close-toed shoes.

Answer (score 1):

With the doors of the shed wide open there should be no problems in starting it up inside the shed to drive it out under its own power.  Those blades better be separate from the drive forward and reverse of the engine.

How much of a tilt is your ramp?  Does your mower sit in the shed flat?  Do not add gasoline/oil within the shed.  If your mower doesn't start on the second ignition then get it out of the shed.  I did this with Harley motorcycles, easier to back down a ramp while on rather than neutral.  Do not store flammables if you are wanting to start in the shed.  Do not smoke?

Easier to back it into the shed after done to roll down going forward the next time you use it.  Clean under the deck and allow to dry before replacing in your shed.  Whenever messing with maintenance always disengage the spark plug.  Remember how they started those propeller antique planes?  They cranked on the propeller and it started the engine and propeller?  Same stuff.  Tilt towards the oil fill of your mower, not away.

Empty your bag of grass and allow it to dry separate from your mower.  Change filters often.  Sharp blades always.